# Simplify SymPy Eq/Equality and Ge/GreaterThan integer expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have this SymPy code:

```
n = Symbol("n", integer=True)
expr = Eq(n, 0) | (n >= 1)
```

I would expect that `expr.simplify()` results in `n >= 0` but it does not.
How can I make this simplification work?

---

I reported that upstream [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18389).

Answer (score 1):

This is a discontinuous set (the point 0 and all points from 1 and greater) so it can't be simplified. The inequality `n >= 0` includes, for example, `n = 1/2` which is not part of the given `expr`.

Comment: But n is an integer.

Comment: Missed that. There is no diophantine solver for inequalities and this case is not simplified in terms of sets, either: `(Eq(n, 0) | (n >= 1)).as_set().intersection(S.Naturals0)) -> Union(FiniteSet(0), Range(1, oo, 1))` though it shouldn't be hard to modify code to collapse FIniteSets into Ranges.